# What is the current reason of answer removal: 'symptoms and how migraine is categorised'?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, deleted-answers

I've [answered](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/141/114) the following question:

- [What are the symptoms of Migraine and how to categorise into severe or mild etc](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/102/what-are-the-symptoms-of-migraine-and-how-to-categorise-into-severe-or-mild-etc)

Initially it was removed by lack of interpretation of migraine stages (I guess) as I was pointed to [help/referencing](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

I've corrected that and flagged the question, it was declined.

I've looked again on the question, especially this part: 'how is the migraine categorised', therefore I've improved my answer to address exactly what OP asked by listing how migraine is categorised (this is only part of the answer):

> There are several types of migraine how it's categorised, such
>   as<sup>[NHS](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/141/114)</sup>:
>
> - migraine with aura,
>
>   This is when there are warning sings before migraine starts (such as
>     flashing lights).
> - migraine without aura,
>
>   Where migraine occurs without warning sings.
> - migraine aura without headache.
>
>   Where other symptoms are experienced (such as aura), but without
>     headache.

As well as 'what are the symptoms' of the migraine which were included there at the very beginning.

However my answer is still removed without clear reason which is:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

So now I don't understand what I should do next. I understand I'll be pointed to thousands of minor issues regarding my answer, but I want to know what is the main reason which prevents this answer to be undeleted.

On my deleted answer I see:

> Why was your post deleted? See: Help.

In [Help Center](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), the main reasons for answer deletion can be:

> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

The only think which is relevant is the last one. But as I've said, my answer answers what was asked ('What are the symptoms of migraine and how to categorise').

Full answer for the reference:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Glaucoma answer removed because of a shotgun approach?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/glaucoma-answer-removed-because-of-a-shotgun-approach)

See Shog's answer here, this is a similar answer.

You provide three types of migraines. You provide no information on the statement "how is the migraine categorised ie whether it is severe, mild etc?". Is a migraine with an aura severe? Mild? How do you tell/know?

Comment: As far as I know it's not categorised into severe or mild so OP asked: 'how is the migraine categorised ie whether it is severe, mild etc?' and he ask if it is not (because he's not sure how), then how it's categorised, therefore I've answered what's the correct categorisation according to NHS. So definitely it's not any shotgun approach.

Comment: Many of your answers appear to share the same characteristics:

    Start with a general-purpose explanation of the question's topic, paraphrased from another site.
    Follow with a list of references and excerpts that may be useful in answering the question
    Close with some related commentary

The most distinctive aspect of these appears to be that, unlike most other answerers, **you often forget to actually answer the question, or obscure your answer within tangential commentary.**

Comment: This is still not clear. The reason is my method of writing? If people don't like my answer or characteristics, down-vote it or comment with suggestions, but not removing it. First silently because of references or too long cites, secondly preventing undelete for any other excuses.

Comment: You actually forgotten to answer mine as well. I've asked for the removal reason. You replied that it doesn't cover 'severe' and 'mild'. I've explained that this is not how NHS categorise migraine. Now it's your turn to explain why my answer is still deleted. I've answered the question correctly, unless you've clear reasons to say otherwise (exempt my personal style which is not relevant).